# I want to set up a pop-up alert when a message sits in the outbox for more than 2 minutes in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

Any email not getting delivered is a huge problem for me at work. I want to make sure it never happens, through some form of a pop-up alert when something is going wrong before it is too late. Please let me know if any ideas.